# How to determine on which UIElement a tagged object is placed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, pixelsense

In my app I use tagged objects. Now I'd like to react differently not only on the object that is placed on the surface, but also on the element it is placed on. Is this possible somehow? I couldn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Please show us your code so we can help you better.

What you are looking for is probably Reflection.

Did you know you can always check if an object is of a certain type with the `is` operator?

```
var tag = myDependencyObject.Tag;
if(myDependencyObject is CheckBox)
{
    //...
}
else if(myDependencyObject is TextBox)
{
    //...
}
```

To detect a change of the Tag-Property, listen to the DependencyPropertyChanged event like this:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor prop = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
    FrameworkElement.TagProperty,
    typeof(FrameworkElement));

prop.AddValueChanged(aTaggedControl, this.YourEventHandlerMethod);
```

Comment: Ah yes thats not really the problem. I just dont know where to catch the event if a tagged object was added. I dont have much code, just added the TagVisualizer to my main layot.

Answer (score 2):

You might do a HitTest. Basically you get the point relative to your window and look which element of the visual tree is being hit. No code sample at hand, but you'll find a lot using HitTest and WPF on google.